# How to plot a binary sequence of data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems that when I use matplotlib.pyplot.plot() I get a rise and fall that uses lines with a slope and offset. I would like to get a straight vertical line from a 0 to a 1 or a 1 to a 0 but thus far haven't been able to get that result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I found this:
[python: How to plot 2D discontinuous node-centered data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774199/python-how-to-plot-2d-discontinuous-node-centered-data?rq=1)
but it seems overly complicated.

Comment: Plesae provide an example for what you want to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for step plot.

You can refer to this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html) for step plot.

A simple example is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, xlim, ylim, show
x = np.arange(0, 7)
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
xlim(0, 7)
ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
step(x, y)
show()
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.